# How to automatically number all the matching strings in a text file?

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I have a text file, **`C:\text\sample.txt`**.  How can I search through this text file , and numbering all instances of a given string (***using regular expression***), for example, word that starts with 'h' and ends with 'y' ?

**What the `sample.txt` looks like: (For this sample file, the regular expression I used is `\bh.+y\b` it'll match happy and history.)**

```
When a happy new history ...
Are you happy ...
How history ... very happy ...
...
```

**The numbering effect I hope to achieve:**

```
When a 1>happy new 2>history ...
Are you 3>happy ...
How 4>history ... very 5>happy ...
...
```

I'm new to python programming. How can I achieve this with python code?

Currently, I only come up with the following codes:

```
import fileinput
import re
for line in fileinput.input('sample.txt',inplace=1):
line = re.sub(r'\bh.+y\b',r'\bh.+y\b', line.rstrip())
```

Comment: What part do you need help with? The regular expression, the opening of the file, the search and replace? Have you tried something that didn't work?

Comment: I know how to open the file, and how to search, replace certain string with regular expression. But I don't know how to automatically number all the mathcing strings.

Comment: Just set a variable to 0 outside of your file-reading-writing loop, and increment it when you find a match. Then add the value of this counter to the word being written back. If you edit the question with what you have so far, it would be easier to recommend the exact fix.

Comment: Ty .. I have edited the question.

Comment: Is their an easier way?   I'm new to programming. And I just hope to find a way to number all the occurences of "a certain string" in a text file. And I hope the way to find that certain string is by using regular expression. Actually ,any solution would be good, as long as it does the job.

Comment: @MrT   Thank you for your suggestions. The question is solved now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand your problem, you need to search a file for a specific pattern, and then pre-pend that match with the total number of matches found so far.

Here is an example that uses `re.sub` and custom function, along with a global counter. You can incorporate this into your code:

```
>>> count = 1
>>> s
'The happy and hungry hippo had a happy meal for lunch.'
>>> def f(m):
...   global count
...   value = '{}-{}'.format(count, m.group())
...   count = count + 1
...   return value
...
>>> re.sub(r'(h\w+y)', f, s)
'The 1-happy and 2-hungry hippo had a 3-happy meal for lunch.'
```

You have to surround the regular expression in `( )` so that the match is captured and returned, in order to modify it.

Comment: Thank you for solving my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have your text file so I just used the text "When a happy new Are you happy How happy very happy" as an exemple to show you a way to solve this problem.

```
word_to_find = "happy"
text_to_count = "When a happy new Are you happy How happy very happy"
text_table = text_to_count.split(" ")
counter = 1
text_output = ""

for i in text_table:
  if i == word_to_find:
    text_output += str(counter) + ">"+ str(i) + " "
    counter += 1
  else:
    text_output += str(i) + " "

print(text_output)
```

This gives you as an output :

```
When a 1>happy new Are you 2>happy How 3>happy very 4>happy
```

You should just replace the variables text_to_count by your text file

If you want to add other words, you can just add them to word_to_find and adjust the if condition

Comment: His problem concern the numbering of words, not the reading file part. I'm quoting him : "I know how to open the file, and how to search, replace certain string with regular expression. But I don't know how to automatically number all the mathcing strings."